# Symfony2 esi cache forms not working

Tags: forms, symfony, caching, esi

I get to the weird situation. I have up to date server files with local files. This "flash message with error" appears when this is not valid:

`if ($form->isValid() && $this->checkLastComment($commentRepository,$user,$status, $comment)) {`

I have two urls. First /Home (working) for everyone where i load statuses with comments BUT I DO NOT CACHE THE PAGE
Then i have /Suggested url where i load statuses with comments BUT USING

```
    $response->setPublic();
    $response->setSharedMaxAge(3600);
```

I CACHE THE PAGE because its the same for all users.

But its weird because on local machine (caching is on i tested) everything runs normal when i want to create a comment... on prod, dev env.

On server it runs normal when i am under dev env.(caching is off) but when i try post comment on prod env. i get error flash message for the mentioned condition...

WTF?  Where could be leak please? i have no idea.

The public esi cache somehow breaks my forms? or...?

One friend is able to post a comment there... another one is not.. weird... i wasn't before but after cache clear i am again able...

EDIT:

After lunch i tried it again and i am not able to post comment... wtf..

This is my header i see in chrome: (sending)

```
CommentForm[comment]:gllll
status_id:65084
CommentForm[_token]:4858119eccbc91da6219d4cbaa1b6c2e79dbd56a
comment_id:0
```

Using this jquery code:

```
    var url=Routing.generate('create_comment', {"comment_id": comment_id_value, "status_id": status_id_value})+'.json';
    $.post(url, $this.serialize(), function(data) {
```

To this controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request, $comment_id=0, $status_id)
{
    // first CHECK if user exists
    $user=$this->getUser();        
    if ($user) {         
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // GET REPOSITORIES
        $statusRepository=$em->getRepository('WallBundle:Status');
        $commentRepository=$em->getRepository('WallBundle:Comments');
        $notifyRepository=$em->getRepository('NotifyBundle:Notify');
        $userRepository=$em->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
        // GET SM
        $SM=$this->get('status_manager');
        // GET status by ID
        $status=$statusRepository->find($status_id);
        // CHECK if this status exists
        if ($status) {
            $targetUser=$status->getUser();
            if ($request->isMethod('POST') && ($this->getRequest()->getRequestFormat() == 'json')) {
                if ($comment_id==0 || !$cE) {
                    $cE = new Comments();
                }

                $form = $this->createForm(new CommentFormType(), $cE);

                $form->bind($request);                    
                     $comment=$form->getData()->getComment();

                 if ($form->isValid() && $this->checkLastComment($commentRepository,$user,$status, $comment)) {
```

AND the checkLastComment function

```
    public function checkLastComment($commentRepository, User $user,Status $status, $comment)
{                    
     // check if last comment was more than 10s ago
     $lastCommentQueryArray=$commentRepository->getLastComment($user, $status); 
     $lastCommentTime=0;
     $lastCommentContent='';
     foreach ($lastCommentQueryArray as $lastComment) {
         $lastCommentTime   =$lastComment['time'];
         $lastCommentContent=$lastComment['comment'];
     }

     if (($lastCommentTime+10>=time()) && (trim($lastCommentContent)==trim($comment))) {
         return false;
     } 
     else {
         return true;
     }
}
```

**But the bug should not be in the code because i am using this technique all over the web and everything runs good... only at this particularly page ITS NOT WORKING ... and the only difference between pages is that this one is cached ... + when i am creating a new comment it has nothing with cache isn't that right? it only takes the data from form which is on cached page... **